# Restore Dynamic Query result in a Variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SP that will return me the next code. I will pass TableName, IdentityColumnName, CodeColumn and ConditionColumn. Simple is that i want to save dynamic query result in a variable, and this query will return a single value to me. This SP will work on 3 tables. The problem is that my dynamic query is not set to `@query` Variable, any help.

```
  ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_GetNextCode]
    (
        @IdColumnName nvarchar(20)= 'HeadId',                
        @CodeColumnName nvarchar(100)= 'HeadCode',           
        @TableName nvarchar(50)= 'Head',                     
        @MaxColumnName varchar(50) = 'FamilyId',             
        @MaxColumnValue varchar(3) = 1                       
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @query varchar(max) , @NewId VARCHAR(30),@LastCode varchar(30)
        ---First Get the Last Inserted Code and save it in a Variable..
        SET @query =    'Select      '+ @LastCode +'='+ @CodeColumnName +'
                        FROM         Account.' + @TableName 
                     + ' Where '    + @IdColumnName + ' = (
                                    SELECT      MAX(' + @IdColumnName + '  ) 
                                    FROM        Account.' + @TableName +'  
                                    where       '+ @MaxColumnName  + ' = ' + @MaxColumnValue  +' )'
        Select @query
        EXEC(@query)
        Select @LastCode
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx) because you want/need to use an output parameter for your dynamic query:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_GetNextCode]
(
    @IdColumnName nvarchar(20)= 'HeadId',                
    @CodeColumnName nvarchar(100)= 'HeadCode',           
    @TableName nvarchar(50)= 'Head',                     
    @MaxColumnName varchar(50) = 'FamilyId',             
    @MaxColumnValue varchar(3) = 1
)
AS
BEGIN

        DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) , @NewId VARCHAR(30),@LastCode varchar(30)
        DECLARE @parms nvarchar(max)
        ---First Get the Last Inserted Code and save it in a Variable..
        SET @query =    'Select      @LastCode='+ @CodeColumnName +'
                        FROM         Account.' + @TableName 
                     + ' Where '    + @IdColumnName + ' = (
                                    SELECT      MAX(' + @IdColumnName + '  ) 
                                    FROM        Account.' + @TableName +'  
                                    where       '+ @MaxColumnName  + ' = ' + @MaxColumnValue  +' )'
        SET @parms = '@LastCode varchar(30) output'
        Select @query
        EXEC sp_executesql @query,@parms,@LastCode output
        Select @LastCode
END
```

At the moment, you're concatenating the *value* of `@LastCode` into your `@query` string - and since it's `NULL`, your entire `@query` string becomes `NULL`.

Comment: Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: Yes, I've tweaked the declarations of `@query` and `@parms` now.